# Stop a specific consumer in MassTransit using RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, masstransit

I want to manually pause a specific consumer contract for a specific period of time. 
Please note that I **do not** want to stop the IServiceBus.
Can I do that with MassTransit (version 7.0.3) and RabbitMQ (version 3.8.5)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to stop an individual consumer, or an individual receive endpoint, without stopping the bus.

If you have transient receive endpoints, you can connect them to the bus (using `ConnectReceiveEndpoint`) after the bus has been started, and stop them using the handle returned.

Comment: I wonder if this is still the case in 2024?

Comment: It's still the case, yes. If you need to start/stop endpoints at runtime, connect them after the bus has been started.